# The number of generators of the ideal of an algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $X\subset k^n$ is an $m>0$ dimensional quasi-affine variety. How can I choose $m$ polinomials generating the ideal $I$ of $X$?

Comment: Why should that be possible? For instance, consider the case $m = 0$...

Comment: Use Gröbner basis.

Comment: How do you mean? @user40276

Comment: There is an algorithm for finding generators using Gröbner basis. But some questions about the number of generators still open.

Comment: If you mean Buchberger's algorithm, I don't see how it is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if $X$ is *quasi*-affine then it is not closed in $k^n$, in general, but just locally closed, and so is not cut ou by an ideal at all.

But even if $X$ is affine, it is hard to tell in general how many polynomials are needed to generated its ideal.  First of all, the natural guess is that you would need $m$ polynomials to cut out an affine variety $X$ of *co*-dimension $m$ (not dimension $m$ as you wrote).  But in general this is just a lower bound; you may need more.

There is a lot of literature on this, including some discussion in the exercises of Hartshorne Ch. I (if I remember correctly).  Googling "complete intersection in affine space" should get you started.